# How to pre-build worker container Dataflow? [Insights "SDK worker container image pre-building: can be enabled"]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm wondering how to pre-build worker container and at the same time use setup.py file for multiple file dependencies.

Even when i used this official template for that i still had Insights: "SDK worker container image pre-building: can be enabled". Is it a bug?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/dataflow/flex-templates/pipeline_with_dependencies

Comment: Please try the updated version on the example. You should no longer see this insight.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm still have the same insight. I'm also curious about removing FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE in the last commit, i tried Dockerw file without this env some time ago and i i had error that modules in my_package directory were missing. How now it is working?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There was a bug in the insight logic. Fix is in flight but will take some time to roll out. If you supply `--sdk_location=container`, that should silence the insight but it is not necessary to supply this flag for any other reason and it won't have an impact on anything else.

Comment: If you use a custom container image, AND install the pipeline package in the image, then supplying FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE is no longer necessary. Otherwise, you need to specify it, so that the template launcher starts the pipeline with a --setup_file pipeline option, which stages the pipeline package and installs it on the workers at runtime. Using a custom container image allows you to pre-install any packages, including the pipeline package, before job submission. The example uses the same image for the flex template  and custom sdk container, the package is installed in the image.

Comment: I suspect you were using the flex  template but did not use a custom SDK container image with your template (did not supply the `--sdk_container_image` pipeline option). in that case, you do need to specify FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE, and the pipeline package will be installed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify additional dependencies for a Python pipeline using flags like  `--requirements_file`, `--setup_file`, `--extra_package`, you can pre-build a container image and install these dependencies before starting a Dataflow Python worker. It  can be accomplished by supplying a `--prebuild_sdk_container_image` pipeline option, see: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/build-container-image#pre-build_a_container_image_when_submitting_the_job . This option might be helpful for users who want to optimize worker startup time, but don't want to build their own custom container manually.

However, when you use a custom container image, it is better to install necessary dependencies directly in the image, when you build it: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/build-container-image#preinstall_using_a_dockerfile . If you do that, you no longer need to supply the pipeline options to install dependencies at runtime, and pre-building workflow is not necessary.

Custom containers provide more control over image customization and result in a more reproducible runtime environments compared to container pre-building.

If a pipeline package is installed in the custom container image, supplying the `--setup_option` is not necessary, unless you made some changes locally that are no longer reflected in the custom image. If you omit `--setup_option`, the insight will not be shown in the next observation period (next day).